# Python ZipFile extractall fails when external_attr is 0x10

Tags: python, zip

I have a peculiar case, where Python's `ZipFile.extractall` fails. I have a few zip files that seem to have been created in an uncommon way (I did not create them, I need to open them). For example, let's discuss a zip files that contains the following files:

```
a/f1.txt
a/f2.txt
b/f3.txt
```

However, the zip file contain the following file entries (as seen by using `ZipFile.filelist`)

```
a/f1.txt, a/f2.txt, a, b/f3.txt, b
```

When trying to use `extractall`, I get an error, saying that the file `a` cannot be created, because it is already a directory (makes sense, as `a/f1.txt` was handled before).

Looking further, the `external_attr` of the proper files is `0x20`. The `external_attr` of the extra files is `0x10`. They are also zero-length.

Window's internal unzip works properly, as does 7zip, but Python's extractall fails.

Is this a bug in Python's ZipFile implementation? Or are these badly encoded zip files that Windows and 7zip just happen to understand? What is going on here?

Note: making the Python code work is simple, just pass all the files without `external_attr==0x10` to `extractall`, but I still want to know what's going on.